# excel word paste command fail

Tags: vba, excel

I am running an excel programme that generates graphs based on data. I then want to export it to word and save it as a pdf.
I am having issues with pasting the diagrams into word as I often get the error 'Run time error '4198' Command Failed' on the Word Paste Special line. I have included by code for the word export below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub word_export(numscans As Integer, rootpath As String, poleid As String)

Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Dim WDApp As Word.Application
Dim WDDoc As Word.Document

Set WDApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WDDoc = WDApp.Documents.Add

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

WDApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

For n = 1 To numscans

    For i = 1 To Sheets("Scan" & n).ChartObjects.Count

        Sheets("Scan" & n).ChartObjects(i).Chart.CopyPicture _
        Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture


        WDApp.Selection.Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False


        WDApp.Selection.MoveEnd wdStory
        WDApp.Selection.Move

    Next

Next

WDDoc.SaveAs rootpath & "\" & poleid & " Summary.pdf", wdFormatPDF
WDApp.Quit wdDoNotSaveChanges

Set WDDoc = Nothing
Set WDApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure about this one, but give it a go:

```
WDApp.Selection.Range.Select
WDApp.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Comment: Unfortunatly same problem occurs

Comment: @user3414481: Then I'm afraid I have no idea. Do not have any Excel to test on either ...